# How do I use mSIGNA without the standard Bitcoin client?

Tags: bitcoin-core, network, msigna

Which IP do I have to fill in in mSIGNA to connect to the Bitcoin Network without using the BitcoinQt/bitcoind application?

Is it possible to use mSIGNA and BitcoinQt even if the syncing process is not finished yet?

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is a way, you need a way to connect to someone running BitcoinQT and who has made their node public. BitcoinQT runs as a node, but to make it discoverable to any but other BitcoinQT wallet users you have to go a step further.

So you need a list of such BitcoinQT "servers", and I found one earlier and in searching for that list of open Bitcoin-QT "servers" someone had published I found this.

If I manage to find it again, I am trying to solve my problem with sending from mSIGNA, I will post a link and more complete answer here.

Comment: A list of nodes can be found here: https://blockchain.info/connected-nodes

Comment: If the list at this link is empty... what does that mean? No bitcoins anymore... ;-)

Answer (score 1):

mSIGNA can connect to any bitcoin node that is publicly available online.  There is a list of nodes that can currently be reached online from [Bitnodes](https://bitnodes.21.co/).  The IP address of any public node can be specified by following the instruction from the [mSIGNA Getting Started Guide](https://ciphrex.com/docs/mSIGNA-Getting_Started.pdf) is excerpted below:

> If you  would   prefer  to  connect to  a   remote  bitcoin node,   you can change
>   the IP  address and port    under   Network->Settings…(File->Preferences
>   …   on  Mac).
>
> NOTE:  mSIGNA™ only    connects    via the peer-to-peer    protocol    and does not    require any special RPC access  to  other   nodes.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's no way to connect without Bitcoin-Qt as Getting Started Tutorial states:

> By    default,    mSIGNA™ will    attempt to  connect to  a   bitcoin node
>   running   on  localhost   (i.e.   a   local   running instance    of  Bitcoin-Qt).    If you
>   have  Bitcoin-Qt  running on  your    computer,   leave   this    setting alone.  If
>   you   would   prefer  to  connect to  a   remote  bitcoin node,   you can change
>   the   IP  address and port    under   Network->Settings… (File->Preferences
>   … on  Mac).